# Choppy sound over bluetooth 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, music

So I'm noticing that listening to music over bluetooth is choppy. I get occasional skipping. Any ideas on how to fix this? I've already tried setting this in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` but this caused all of my devices including the Bluetooth headset to disappear from the audio window.

```
#load-module module-udev-detect
module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Followed by:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

For the record, it does seem like a scheduling issue to me but IDK how to fix.
Ideas?

Further requested info:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb 
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:855c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
0c:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 1f75:0917 Innostor Technology Corporation 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1b1c:0c04 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:17cf ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1e7d:3264 ROCCAT 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1e7d:2d51 ROCCAT Kone+ Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1058:0740 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Essential (WDBACY)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I am afraid there is no solution for Broadcom.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: BT and Wi-Fi use the same RF frequency. Broadcom drivers can't handle this well.

Comment: I'm not using WiFi.

Comment: Then it is something else.

Comment: IMHO there is a solution for everything even if it's "Write your own drivers." or "Get some different hardware.". ;-)

Comment: Actually WiFi was enabled but AFIK, not connected. I've disabled it to see if this helps.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I do seem to be noticing some improvement. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Post as answer and I will give u the cheddar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth and 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi share the same radio frequency.

Some wireless drivers can handle it well, but sometimes the coexistence technology has to be enabled in configs.

With Broadcom Wi-Fi+BT chips there is no way to change anything there. The only way to improve BT performance is to disable Wi-Fi, or use only 5GHz.

Comment: Ironically fiddling with this has re-triggered the old fluctuating sound issue.